# How can I allow menu scrolling in Ubuntu 18.04/19 like it is for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: menu, scrolling

I am porting program from Linux Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 and 19. I am using appindicator-1.0 in conjunction with Gtk+2.0 menu. Menu consist of constant items and many dynamically added items. If the screen pixel resolution is not so good as it must be then the last menu items are not visible. Ubuntu 16.04 automatically add top and bottom bars with "^" and "v" arrows to scroll menu when mouse pointer is over these bars. But in Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and 19 such scrolling bars are not appearing! Where have I to dig to resolve this issue?